# npm link not resolving

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have two barebones react apps. I'm trying to import a component from one into the other, and my `link` command isn't enough to resolve the module I need.

```
cd ~/workspace/export-test
npm link

cd ~/workspace/import-test
npm link export-test
npm run build

ERROR in ./src/HelloWorld.js 2:0-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'export-test' in '/Users/username/workspace/import-test/src'
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

### ~/workspace/import-test/

```
// src/HelloWorld.js
import { ImportMe } from 'export-test'

// package.json
// The exact same as export-test, except for name
```

### ~/workspace/export-test/:

```
// src/index.js
...
import ImportMe from './ImportMe';
render(<ImportMe />, document.getElementById('root'));
...

// src/ImportMe.js
const ImportMe = () => {
    return <h1>I have been imported!</h1>;
};
export default ImportMe;

// package.json
{
"name": "export-test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.10.0"
}
```

### Misc.

```
npm list -g
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/lib
├── export-test@1.0.0 -> ./../../../../../workspace/export-test
```

Comment: Please show `package.json` of both projects. Also, show how you export your component.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski my question is updated

Comment: Try changing `"main": "index.js"` to `"main": "src/index.js"`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I think that did it...

Comment: You will still have some import issues probably because you don't export anything from this `src/index.js`, but yes, it should do. Sadly `main` is not specified in the documentation of `npm link`. I'm not surprised that you didn't know this

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Can I just add `export default ImportMe` at the end of `index.js`?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to use `import ImportMe from 'export-test'` instead. If you still want to use `import { ImportMe } from 'export-test'` you have to use `export `ImportMe` You can also point your `main` into other files than `index.js` I wouldn't recommend exporting the file where you also use `render` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it clear.

When `npm link` is used `main` property in `package.json` have to point to a file you want to export.

In this case, it was `index.js`, but it should be `src/index.js`